# current directory doesn't appear in title bar when running under screen

Tags: linux, prompt, gnu-screen, xterm

My xterm `$prompt` variable in my `.tcshrc` is:

```
set prompt="%{\033]0;%m:%~\007%}%{^[[;37;1m%}%B%{^[[;34;1m%}%m%{^[[;34;1m%}:%b%c%# "
```

The ***highlighted*** part above (`%{\033]0;%m:%~\007%}`) puts the hostname (`%m`) and the current directory (`%~`) in the title bar.  (At least I *think* that that's what puts it in the title bar; it's been a while since I fiddled with this prompt).

When I run `screen`, however, the current directory stops getting updated when I change directories.

My questions:

1. How can I make this prompt work in screen?
2. Is there a better way to display the current directory in the title bar?

I am running linux with xterm and tcsh.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no direct way, because of the way screen works. However screen can display its own status bar, that you can define in .screenrc. Here's mine for instance :

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
 hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%=%{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

Comment: If instead of %t %h is used, then the sequence from the OP will show on the hardstatus

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, to make it work you must check where exactly is the line with `set prompt=blah-blah` in your `.tcshrc`. For example, the code below that perfectly works in plain xterm **would not** work under screen in xterm:

```
switch ($TERM)
case "xterm*":
  set prompt="%{\033]0;${HOME:t}@%m:%l:%c08\007%}%{\033[36m%}%l:%c02%#%{\033[0m%} "
  # update xterm title to display current cmd in it
  alias postcmd 'echo -n "\033]0;${HOME:t}@`hostname`:${tty}    \!#:q\007"'
...
```

because screen by default sets $TERM variable to `screen` and not `xterm`! So you must add:

```
case "screen":
  # lame, but prevents an error in screen after 'su - root'
  if (! $?WINDOW) setenv WINDOW 1
  set prompt="%{\033]0;${HOME:t}@%m:${WINDOW}:%c08\007%}%{\033[36m%}%c02%#%{\033[0m%} "
  alias postcmd 'echo -n "\033]0;${HOME:t}@`hostname`:${WINDOW}    \!#:q\007"'
  ...
```

**Secondly**, make sure yo have this line in `~/.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm* 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;\007'
```